# Lambda to trigger aws batch job on the other account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-batch

I need to trigger the aws batch job from my lambda function. However, the batch job is on the other aws account. How do I ensure that my lambda function has premission to execute the batch job on another account? Would assume role policy be enough? Btw: I have the IAM user keys for the other account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Lambda functions can assume roles to trigger actions in other accounts. Here is a complete example from the AWS documentation on how to access an S3 bucket from a lambda in account A to account B.

https://repost.aws/es/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role

As explained at the start of the document:

Lambda function can assume an IAM role in another AWS account to do either of the following:

- Access resources— For example, accessing an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket.
- **Do tasks—For example, starting and stopping instances.**

Comment: I'm using the node.js SDK. Do I just pass the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey into the BatchClient parameters during initialization?

Comment: Here you have some documentation on how to do it from js sdk https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/example_sts_AssumeRole_section.html